# How to change html pages path sphinx

Tags: python-sphinx

I write documentation using Sphinx.

Now pages path is "folder/html/". I want to replace it with "folder/" . I tried to change BUILDDIR, but it did't help.

How to do it? I use windows

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace parameter `-M` in Makefile and make.bat with `-b`.

###### Details

When running [`sphinx-build`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-build.html) with the `-b` option, the output directory is what you set it to be.

When using the `-M` option, it does not work exactly the same. The "html" subdirectory (the buildername) is always added. See this bug report: https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/6896.