# Sphinx RtD: change the output folder name

Tags: python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I would like to change the Sphinx / Read-the-Docs `make html` output **folder name** to 'docs' rather than 'html'. Is there a way to do this? I've been going over the conf.py documentation and the only thing that looks close to what might do it is:

html_baseurl = 'docs'

but it does nothing: the output folder name defaults to 'html'.

Comment: The output directory is an argument to sphinx-build (https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-build.html), which is called from the Makefile. See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/71875843/407651

Comment: Thank you. I did read that sphinx-build documentation, but you pointed me to the key: changing the -M to -b in the Makefile SPHINXBUILD statements (I did it for both help and #@), where it now respects my path entry for BUILDDIR. This makes updating my github gh-pages so much more seamless!

Answer (score 1):

You can run the `sphinx-build` command by hand, you do not need to use the supplied Makefile.

```sh
sphinx-build -M html "docs/source" "whatever/docs"
```